# What is an alternative solution to NAT hairpin?

Tags: networking, router, dns, bind

I recently came across an annoying problem.
I have Ubuntu server running in my home network that runs web server, DHCP and DNS. I successfully exposed it using DMZ, so I could access it from the Internet. Due to the fact that my ISP provides me with dynamic IP address I had to configure dynamic DNS to point to my dynamic address. So I did, obtaining let's say `noip.ddns.net`. After that I purchased a domain name (let's name it `mydomain.com`) and pointed the nameservers to `noip.ddns.net`. Then I created a simple script that updates `A` records for `mydomain.com` on a home server Bind server. Everything works well outside of my network (no problems accessing `sub.mydomain.com`) however when I try to access `sub.mydomain.com` from my LAN it shows me the ISP router page. Then I configured a separate view on Bind9 server so whenever a device from LAN tries to resolve `mydomain.com` it gets the local address. The DNS seems to work (pinging from LAN return local address but pinging from the outside returns global address).
However whenever I try to access the server from LAN it still shows the ISP page (despite correct local IP mapping - verified via ping command). Obviously when I enter local IP instead of domain name it works, but then I cannot access defined subdomains. One thing I noticed is that when I enter the same local address in the `hosts` file, then it works fine. What might be a case of such a behavior? In both cases my browser cache as well as IP addresses and DNS addresses were cleared.
I found that a solution might be a router supporting NAT hairpin however mine is not capable of doing so I would ask if there is any way to workaround this problem without replacing the router so that I could access my subdomains from LAN.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115440/discussion-on-question-by-kwojcikowski-what-is-an-alternative-solution-to-nat-ha).

Comment: What web browser(s) are you testing with? Newer versions of Chrome and Firefox can use [DoH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS) instead of using a local DNS resolver. (Firefox goes to 1.1.1.1 and Chrome might go to there or to 8.8.8.8.)